# how to using dateadd in sqlalchemy with filter?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, turbogears, dateadd

The sql expression :

```sql
select * 
  from order 
 where status=0 
   and adddate(created_time, interval 1 day)>now();
```

python code:

```python
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func, text
from datetime import datetime 

closed_orders = DBSession.query(Order).filter(func.dateadd(Order.create_time,         text('interval 1 day'))>datetime.now()).all()
```

but it's got wrong. how to do it correctly?

thanks

REF :[Using DATEADD in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572292/using-dateadd-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by wrong?
Could you add what output you get and what output you'd expect?

Comment: I change "func.dateadd"  to "func.adddate"
Then it works!.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
import datetime
DBSession.query(Order)\
    .filter(func.ADDDATE(Order.create_time,1)>datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

presto:

```
extract('hour', cast(t_table.open_time,TIMESTAMP)) - 5 == 12

extract('dow', cast(cast(t_table.open_time, TIMESTAMP) - 5,TIMESTAMP)) == 3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks