# SQLAlchemy: adding Integer column to DateTime

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a table

```
class Order(db.Model):
  created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  days = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I need to compose a query with FROM statement like this: `Order.created_at + Order.days < datetime.now()`. The simplest way doesn't work, since the result of addition integer to datetime is double :) This conclusion I've made after practical experiment with MySQL.

After searching a little I've found out correct SQL statement for MySQL which solves described issue:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
WHERE o.created_at + INTERVAL o.days DAY < '2014-06-10 14:22:00';
```

And what I'd like to ask is how to code the query above for sqlalchemy filter? 
I've found one article [how to use Intervals here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573750), but `DATEADD` is missing in MySQL and I have no ideas where I need to bind an Interval.

Sorry for my poor English, I hope I could explain my problem correct :)

UPD: Maybe the right thing to define `days` as Interval, but currently it's not an option.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has a function called [TIMESTAMPADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) which seems to do what you want.  Here's how to use it in a query.

```
session.query(Order).filter(func.timestampadd(text('DAY'), Order.days, Order.created_at) < datetime(2014, 6, 10, 14, 22))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func

query = (session.query(Orders).filter(
             func.DATEADD('day', Orders.days, Orders.created_at) == '2014-06-10 14:22:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone using PSQL / SQlAlchemy 1.0.10+ you can use the below:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import cast
db = SQLAlchemy()  # Instantiated 

Order.query.filter(
    Order.created_at > cast('1 DAY', db.Interval) * Order.day
).all()
```