# Flask Sqlalchemy compare two dates of two related tables

Tags: python, date, sqlalchemy

I have two related tables, User and UserDownload, now I want to filter out UserDownload which it's created_at is bigger than the created_at of the user plus one day, so the python code is :

`result = db.session.query(UserDownload.uid).join(User, UserDownload.uid == User.id).filter(UserDownload.created_at >= User.created_at + timedelta(days=1)).all()`

it's logic seems correct, but the result is weird, some result, the created time of user plus one day is little than the created_at of UserDownload, but some are not . and the raw sql I check the string of the query is :

`SELECT user_downloads.uid AS user_downloads_uid \nFROM user_downloads JOIN users ON user_downloads.uid = users.id \nWHERE user_downloads.created_at >= users.created_at + :created_at_1`

really don't know what :created_at_1 means.

for example, the result contains a such user_download(I replace UserDownload.uid with UserDownload, and query User by its uid):

`user_download.created_at: datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 3, 8, 39, 56)
user.created_at: datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 2, 11, 7, 14)`

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @SuperShoot I use Mysql as my database, and sqlalchemy as my orm in flask. SQLAlchemy==1.0.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the backend that you are using, you need your filter to generate sql like (for mysql):

```
...WHERE user_downloads.created_at >= DATE_ADD(users.created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

SQLAlchemy doesn't convert arithmetic between a `datetime` object and an `InstrumentedAttribute` object into that `DATE_ADD` (or equivalent depending on backend) function. So where you filter by this:

```
UserDownload.created_at >= User.created_at + timedelta(days=1)
```

it gets converted to this:

```
...WHERE user_downloads.created_at >= users.created_at + :created_at_1
```

where it treats `timedelta(days=1)` as a literal value, and parameterises it. That is what the `:created_at_1` is, a parameter that holds the place in the query for the `timedelta` object which will be passed along with the query to the server (as a side note, in MySQL that `timedelta` actually gets converted into a `datetime` object that is epoch + 1 day, as MySQL doesn't have a native `INTERVAL` type).

So to get the query to do what you want, you need to use the `sqlalchemy.func` object to generate the server side function that you need. Continuing with the MySQL example, an appropriate query might be:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, text

q = session.query(UserDownload.uid).\
    join(User, UserDownload.uid == User.id).\
    filter(
        UserDownload.created_at >=
        func.DATE_ADD(
            User.created_at,
            text('INTERVAL 1 DAY')
        )
    )
```

Which generates:

```
SELECT user_downloads.uid
FROM user_downloads INNER JOIN users ON user_downloads.uid = users.id
WHERE user_downloads.created_at >= DATE_ADD(users.created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I found this question helpful: [Using DATEADD in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572292/using-dateadd-in-sqlalchemy)

**From the comments**

> since mysql can handle timedelta(days=1) params, why the query I used
>   fails.

OK, I'll try to go into more detail about your original query, but give me some latitude as I'm working this out as I go. Lets forget about the `timedelta` for a second and just see what the sql generated is. So this:

```
session.query(UserDownload.uid).join(User, UserDownload.uid == User.id).filter(UserDownload.created_at >= User.created_at)
```

generates this sql:

```
SELECT user_downloads.uid AS user_downloads_uid
FROM user_downloads INNER JOIN users ON user_downloads.uid = users.id
WHERE user_downloads.created_at >= users.created_at
```

Nothing hard to grok there. Now when we add back in the `timedelta` the sql generated is exactly the same except that we add a value on to `users.created_at` which is represented by the bind parameter `created_at_1`:

```
SELECT user_downloads.uid AS user_downloads_uid
FROM user_downloads INNER JOIN users ON user_downloads.uid = users.id
WHERE user_downloads.created_at >= users.created_at + %(created_at_1)s
```

So is the comparison executed first, or the addition? Running this query...

```
print(engine.execute(text("SELECT 3 >= 2 + 2")).fetchall())
```

... returns `0` (i.e. `False`), which proves that the addition (`2 + 2`) is resolved before the comparison (`>=`). So safe to assume that happens in your query too and from that, the value of `created_at_1` is added to `users.created_at` *prior* to the comparison with `user_downloads.created_at`. When I execute your query, this is the parameter value passed to the server:

```
{'created_at_1': datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 0)}
```

So even though you add `timedelta(days=1)` to `users.created_at` in your filter, SQLAlchemy actually passes a `datetime` object equivalent to `<epoch> + <timedelta>`, or in this case: `datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0) + timedelta(days=1)` or `datetime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 0)` (which is the value that you see in the parameter value dictionary above).

So what exactly is the value of `user.created_at + datetime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 0)`? I added a `User` instance into the database with `created_at = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)`:

```
session.add(User(id=1, created_at=datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)))
session.commit()
```

Then ran this query:

```
engine.execute(text("SELECT created_at + :a FROM users"), a=datetime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 0)).fetchall()
```

which returned:

```
[(19700101001970.0,)]
```

That is the value of `user.created_at` without any formatting, with the year portion of the `datetime(1970, 1, 2, 0, 0)` concatenated to the end. So that is what your query is comparing to `user_download.created_at`. For the sake of (relative) brevity, I'm not going to look into how the comparison of `user_download.created_at` and that value works, but hopefully I've demonstrated that the end result of your query is not comparing `user_download.created_at` with `users.created_at` plus 1 day.

> when I use query like: User.query.filter(User.created_at >
>   datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)), it works fine.

Using that query, here is the generated sql:

```
SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.created_at AS users_created_at
FROM users
WHERE users.created_at > %(created_at_1)s
```

and the value passed on to the server is:

```
{'created_at_1': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 21, 21, 38, 51, 670890)}
```

So you can see that the `datetime + timedelta` part is resolved *before* being passed to the database and as such, the database operation is a simple comparison of a `DATETIME` column to a `datetime` value.

Comment: Thanks, It helps. But I still have a question, since mysql can handle timedelta(days=1) params, why the query I used fails. Btw, when I use query like: 
 User.query.filter(User.created_at > datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)), it works fine. Is it because you can't do the date add between python object and the column in database?

Comment: I've added to the answer above to try and address your extra questions.

Comment: btw, 19700101001970.0, means the original date plus 19min and 70 seconds to me. and when I migrate the original data to mongo, and query it by aggregate, it seems like the origin query filter out user_download bigger than user created_at plus  about 20mins.